# How to change date 2012-03-24 to 03/24/2013 in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, date-formatting, advanceddatagrid

```
    override public function set data(value:Object):void
    {

        super.data = value;

        if(data["date"] == ' ') 
        {

                var d:DateFormatter =  new DateFormatter();

                var month4:String = String(value);
                d.formatString = "MM-YY";

        data["date"] =d.format(DateFormatter.parseDateString(month4));
        }       



    }
```

I want to change the value which is coming from database as 2013-03-24 to 03/24/2013 please tell how to do that... I do not need any hard code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format date, just add `formatString` property of `dateField` component like `formatString="MM/DD/YYYY"`. It will display your date as provided format. Flex `dateFiled` component already have this functionality.